# silly problem with calling python script from qt creator

Tags: python, qt-creator

some of my friend try to run some google translate script from qtcreator, problem is this is not working

she tried various attempts but it dont work.. the pronlem is the command to execute is in form:

```
 python_path script_path "text to translate " -s pl -d fr
```

she dont know how to make it work with those `""` signs she used `\"` but it then dont work

```
QString cmdCommand = "D:/Qt_workspace/weatherBot/venv/python.exe D:/Qt_workspace/weatherBot/venv/Lib/googletrans-2.4.0/translate.py \" gdzie jest kot \" -s pl -d fr";
```

end it is called by

```
    QProcess *qprocess= new QProcess;
    qprocess->start(cmdCommand);
```

how to make it work?

Comment: how about `QString cmdCommand = "D:/Qt_workspace/weatherBot/venv/python.exe ";
QStringList args;
args.append("D:/Qt_workspace/weatherBot/venv/Lib/googletrans-2.4.0/translate.py");
args.append(" gdzie jest kot ");
args.append(" -s pl -d fr");
qprocess->start(cmdCommand, args);`

Comment: i will tell her to check

Comment: she say it dont give results

Comment: note if she calls  ```D:/Qt_workspace/weatherBot/venv/python.exe D:/Qt_workspace/weatherBot/venv/Lib/googletrans-2.4.0/translate.py " gdzie jest kot " -s pl -d fr``` from console by hand it works, it dont work when called from qt

Comment: you can use `"` inside `'` - like `'wlaz kotek na "płotek" i mruga'`

Comment: what means "not working" ? Is it crash of display error message when you run program in console/terminal/cmd.exe ? Maybe it display some useful information in consol.

Comment: now i released that you add tag `python` but it is C++ code and you can't use `'` like in Python. And your problem is C++, not Python.

Comment: I think you run procees in wrong way - you have to run `start(program, arguments)`. If you use one string then it thinks it is long name of program, not program with arguments. And argument may have to be as list, not as one string. It is common method to run program. In python and probably in C you would have to run `['python_path', 'script_path',  '"text to translate"', '-s',  'pl', '-d', 'fr']`

Comment: @vk-code I think your idea is correct but you would have to split `" -s pl -d fr"` into separated elements `append("-s")`, `append("pl")`, `append("-d")`, `append("fr")`

Comment: she finally used qprocess->write("-s pl -d fr"); or something like that (i write from head) and it began to work...topic closed..tnx for yr attention